# Laptop CPU overheats when turbo boost is active

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling, turbo-boost

My laptop is shutting down if I have **turbo boost** enabled, it does not matter which OS I'm using, I have tried a lot of things like clean install, drivers, monitoring but it seems that the only solution is that I disable the feature.

CPU: **i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz** (not overclocked)

[laptop info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyNtk.png)

What happens is when I open a few applications, while they are opening,  it spikes the temperature over or close to 100 °C and if it does reach it, overheat warning is sent to the OS and it automatically turns the system off.

If I have the feature off, it runs really fine, but it still bothers me that I have to turn it off and I'm completely out of ideas.

Got this laptop about 6 months ago so I still have warranty on it, should I take it back or it's not that big of a deal and **re-applying thermal paste** would solve it?

Any other idea that would fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Re-applying the thermal paste on a new computer would likely void the
warranty, so is not recommended.

I would recommend instead returning the laptop, if you can still
be reimbursed. Otherwise, ask for repairs.